# How do I get my insurance to treat an ambulance charge for a 5150 transfer as "in network"?

Tags: united-states, insurance, health-insurance

My daughter became suicidal and after taking her to our local emergency room she was placed on a 5150 and was subsequently transferred to the nearest inpatient mental health faculty. Our local hospital has no psychiatric inpatient facilities. We were told that we had no choice in the facility it was on a basis of which one had a bed open at the time. This was also during COVID and she had to have a negative test to enter any facility. When a bed was open an ambulance showed up and she was transferred (approximately 70 minute ride). The bill for the ambulance was $4780. Because the ambulance service was out of network and we had not met our "out of network" deductible we are on the hook for the whole $4780. I have Blue Sheild PPO of California. I was unaware that we had separate deductibles for "in network" and "out of Network" providers. I had assumed because we had met our "individual out of pocket max" for my daughter that the cost would be completely covered. It was a real eye opener to realize my plan had separate deductibles. Wow!!! read all the pages of your coverage. My problem is that I felt I had no choice in the ambulance service that the hospital used. My question is," How best to approach my insurance company about this charge?" I have spoken with the ambulance company and they said they have already adjusted the cost to reflect what it would have been had they been in network. Has anyone had any luck in getting an insurance company to change "out of network" to "in network" charges? Is a 5150 transfer considered an emergency? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. As it is, it is hard to come up with a definitive answer. This site acts more like a wiki where we upvote the response that best answers your question. It isn't really a discussion board. However, if you'd like to discuss please feel free to do so in the chat area. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22/show-me-the-money

Comment: I don't know about California, but it is very common for all ambulance services to be out of network. Balance billing is also common, where you are responsible for any amount not covered by insurance. It's frustrating given how little control you have over it.